# Window function over 30 days but missing rows

Tags: sql-server, date, window-functions

I'm trying to get a running total for how many of each product have been sold in the last 30 days, in addition to how many were sold each day. I tried to do this with a window function between preceding and current row but the problem is that products don't always make a sale every day, so my window function is looking back 30 rows instead of 30 days.

Sample data looks like:

```
date       | prod_id | sales | wrong_answer | correct_answer
2016-09-22   123       5       5              5
2016-09-24   123       2       7              7
2016-09-30   123       5       12             12
2016-10-01   123       4       16             16
2016-10-06   123       6       22             22
2016-10-18   123       4       26             26
2016-10-20   123       6       32             32
2016-11-04   123       14      46             30
2016-11-05   123       40      86             70
2016-11-25   123       30      116            94
2016-11-26   123       9       125            103
2016-12-10   123       12      137            115
2016-12-12   123       8       145            123
2016-12-16   123       4       149            127
2016-12-31   123       3       152            130
2017-01-09   123       4       156            134
2016-09-22   456       etc     etc            etc
```

My query is:

```
SELECT
  date,
  prod_id,
  sales,
  SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_id OVER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as wrong_answer
FROM prod_sales
```

As you can see when the date hits 2016-11-04 wrong_answer is still looking back 30 rows instead of 30 days. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps use a subquery? e.g. give your table an alias (like `PS`) and have `mycolumn = (select sum(sales) from prod_sales where datediff(day, date, PS.date) between 0 and 30)`

Comment: This had been discussed in great detail on dba.se: [Date range rolling sum using window functions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/date-range-rolling-sum-using-window-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting window of 30 days..

```
 select t1.[date], t1.prod_id, t1.sales, 
(select distinct sum(sales) over(order by prod_id)
from prod_sales as t2 where 
t2.date<= t1.date and t2.date > dateadd(day,-30,t1.date) and t2.prod_id = t1.prod_id) 
from prod_sales as t1
```

If you are setting window of 1 month..

```
select t1.[date], t1.prod_id, t1.sales, 
(select distinct sum(sales) over(order by prod_id)
from prod_sales as t2 where 
t2.date<= t1.date and t2.date > dateadd(month,-1,t1.date) and t2.prod_id = t1.prod_id) 
from prod_sales as t1
```

Note: Getting a bit different from your correct answer... correct me if i didn't get your question properly.

Comment: Yep the first one is what I'm looking for, starting from 30 days ago. Actually the results in correct_answer had a 31 day window. This works great

Thanks Pramod!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post, but I guess just aggregating in the subquery will also work:

```
select t1.`date`, t1.prod_id, t1.sales,
   # use subquery to aggregate
(
    select sum(sales)
    from sample_sales as t2
    where subdate(t1.date, 30) < t2.date and t2.date<= t1.date and t2.prod_id = t1.prod_id
) sales_30_days
from sample_sales as t1;
```

at least I got the same result from Pramod's answer :).